# Obtaining a nested class within a div using GWT RootPanel calls

Tags: gwt

I am trying to get to the Object within my GWT code the div class ="left" from the GWT code. I am able to get the content with RootPanel.get call but not the nested elements in the html. Can you pls suggest,

```
<div id="content">

<div class="left">
<div class="articles">

<br /><br />
<img src="images/mobicollaborate-1.png" alt="Example pic" style="border: 3px solid #ccc;" />
<br /><br />


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your application, are you doing a `RootPanel.get("content").add(myWidget)`?

Comment: Actually I want to add a widget to "left" and "articles" div class. I can get the "content" thru the RootPanel.get call and add to it.

Comment: Is there an api to get to these two elements under the div id "content".

Answer (score 0):

Give unique Id for div's with class left and articles. say

```
<div id="leftDiv" class="left">
<div id="articlesDiv" class="articles">
```

Then in your code,

RootPanel.get("leftDiv").add(Instance of your widget to be added to left div);
RootPanel.get("articlesDiv").add(Instance of your widget to be added to articles div);

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Appreciate the prompt response.